# How to properly connect models and custom classes in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I do not understand how to properly connect the model and filter. I implemented this using Dependency Injection in the controller, but I don’t like the fact that it needs to be done in every method where filtering should be applied. It would be very convenient if the model itself understood which class with filters to use.

Tell me how to do better.

Filtration Class:

```php
namespace App\Classes\Filter;

class QueryFilter
{
    protected $query;
    protected $params;

    public function apply($query, $params)
    {
        $this->query = $query;
        $this->params = $params;

        foreach ($this->filters() as $filter => $value){
            if(method_exists($this, $filter)){
                $this->$filter($value);
            }
        }

        return $this->query;
    }

    public function filters()
    {
        return $this->params;
    }
}
```

Heirs implement filters for different models:

```php
namespace App\Classes\Filter;

class PositionFilter extends QueryFilter
{

    public function title($value)
    {
        $this->query->where('title', 'LIKE', "%$value%");
    }

}

class GasStationFilter extends QueryFilter
{

    public function number($value)
    {
        $this->query->where('number', 'LIKE', "%$value%");
    }

    public function region($value)
    {
        $this->query->whereHas('region', function ($query) use ($value){
           $query->where('regions.id', $value);
        });
    }
}
```

In the controller, I inject the desired class with filters and apply filtering like this (I use scope in the model):

```php
    public function index(GasStationIndexRequest $request, GasStationFilter $filters)
    {
        $gasStations = GasStation::with('region')
            ->filter($request->validated(), $filters)
            ->take(10)
            ->get();

        return GasStationSelect2Resource::collection($gasStations);
    }
```

Model:

```php
namespace App\Models;

class GasStation extends ListModel
{
    public function region(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Region::class);
    }

    public function scopeFilter($query, $params, $filters) : Builder
    {
        return $filters->apply($query, $params);
    }


}
```

Comment: Got a response in Russian stackoverflow https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1032668/354352